# Using C++ to match parentheses, braces and brackets

Tags: c++

We're supposed to implement a program to check whether the braces, brackets and parens in a given expression all match using a stack structure in C++ for my CS class. Unfortunately, I'm kinda stuck on this one, since I keeps telling me something doesn't match, even when it most decidedly does.
Here's what I got so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct cell {int value; cell* next; };
cell* top;
int numElem;

void init()
{
    top = NULL;
    numElem = 0;
}

int pop()
{
    int res;
    if (top != NULL)
    {
        res = top -> value;
        top = top -> next;
        numElem--;
    } else {
        cout << "FAIL: Stack empty!\n";
        res = -1;
    }
    return res;
}

void push(int element)
{
    cell* cat = new cell;
    cat -> value = element;
    cat -> next = top;
    top = cat;
}

void match(char expr[])
{
    bool pass = true;
    char expected;
    char encountered;
    char closing;
    for (int i=0; pass && (i<strlen(expr)); i++)
    {
        if ((i==40)||(i==91)||(i==123))
            push(i);
        else 
        {
            if (i==41)
                expected = 40;
            if (i==93)
                expected = 91;
            if (i==125)
                expected = 123;
            encountered = pop();
            if (expected != encountered)
                closing = i;
                pass = false;
        }
    }
    if (pass)
        cout << "Parentheses match OK!\n";
    else
        cout << encountered << " has opened, but closing " << closing;
        cout << " encountered!\nParentheses do not match\n";
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    init();
    match(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Since the stack framework existed from a previous exercise and worked fine there, I'm strongly assuming whatever error there is should be in `void match`

Comment: Not the problem you are looking for but you **need** to avoid performance problems: calling `strlen(expr)` in every iteration turn the linear algorithm into a quadratic one. I don't know how you ended up using built-in strings rather than `std::string` in the first place...

Comment: Minor suggestion: I'd give names to the characters you're looking for:  `enum { open_paren = '(', close_paren = ')', open_bracket = '[', close_bracket = ']', open_brace = '{', close_brace = '}' };`

Comment: For the sake of readability, I'd change from `40`, `41`, `93`, `91`, etc., to `'['`, `']'`, `'('`, `')'`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your match function you should test characters, not their indices:

```
void match(char expr[])
{
...
    for (int i=0; pass && (i<strlen(expr)); i++)
    {
        char c = expr[i]; // use this c instead of i below!!!!!!!
        if ((c==40)||(c==91)||(c==123))
            push(c);
        else 
        {
            if (c==41)
                expected = 40;
            if (c==93)
                expected = 91;
            if (c==125)
...
```

Also you did not update counter in your push:

```
void push(int element)
{
...
   ++numElems; // Was missing!!!!
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I usually don't miss stuff like that, but it was getting really late and tiresome ^^

Answer (score 5):

```
else
    cout << encountered << " has opened, but closing " << closing;
    cout << " encountered!\nParentheses do not match\n";
```

The second line always prints. It should be

```
else
{
    cout << encountered << " has opened, but closing " << closing;
    cout << " encountered!\nParentheses do not match\n";
}
```

Also

```
if (expected != encountered)
            closing = i;
            pass = false;
```

should also be

```
if (expected != encountered)
{
            closing = i;
            pass = false;
}
```

Do you come from python? Indentation doesn't affect logic in C++, it just affects readability.

Comment: This is why you should always **always** use braces around code blocks.

Comment: funny, I had the first one on one line and changed it so the formatting wouldn't be off, but the second one really was like that.

Didn't really help though, it changed the program's behavior from rejecting everything to accepting everything.

Comment: yes i did infact use gdb all along the way, but since there is no runtime error it didn't really help.

Comment: @Axim oh, I see. In that case, the best advice anyone can give you at this stage is to learn how to use a debugger. It's a definite must.